# Diferencias ArrayList<Object> con ArrayList<ClaseCustom>

Tags: java, revisión-de-código

**Contexto:** (pregunta al final)

En los proyectos con los que trabajamos tenemos clases en java que son las representaciones de tablas de base de datos. Lo que serían las entidades.

Y en todas las clases tenemos una variable ArrayList llamada `queryResults` que es donde almacenamos la lista de registros de bbdd cuando hacemos los select.

En antiguas clases de java generadas hace años me he fijado que la variable esta de la siguiente manera:

```
private ArrayList<Object> queryResults = null;
```

El problema con esto, que luego al utilizarla hay que castearla a la clase que almacena y no podemos llamarla directamente, sino que hay que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cliente.getQueryResults().size(); i++){
  Cliente holder = (Cliente) foo.getQueryResults().get(i);
  String nombre = holder.getNombre();
  //Resto de lógica
}
```

En cambio si cuando creamos la clase por ejemplo `Cliente` creamos la variable de esta manera:

```
private ArrayList<Cliente> queryResults = null;
```

Cuando trabajamos con ella, no hace falta castearla y si que podemos directamente trabajar con los registros del ArrayList.

```
for(int i = 0; i < cliente.getQueryResults().size(); i++){
  String nombre = cliente.getQueryResults().get(i).getNombre();
  //Resto de lógica
}
```

**Mi pregunta es:**
¿Que implicaciones tiene, crear un ArrayList de una clase dentro de la propia clase? Ejemplo:

```
public class Cliente(){
    private ArrayList<Cliente> queryResults = null;

    public Cliente(){

    }

    private String nombre = null;
    private String apellidos = null;

    //getters setters
}
```

Comment: Dentro de una clase puedes tener una lista de objetos de la misma clase, no hay ningún problema en ello. Lo único que veo un poco raro es que guardes los resultados de la query en la misma clase en la que guardas los datos de un cliente individual. Sin saber más de la aplicación parece que tu clase Cliente hace demasiadas cosas, y que se podría separar en otras clases.

Comment: Mi duda principal era esa, si podría dar algún problema crear una lista de una clase dentro de la propia clase, con tu comentario y la respuesta de @Reynald0 me confirmáis que no pasa nada, de todas formas el equipo de programadores tenemos claro que hace cada clase y comentamos siempre el código, así que gracias por aclarármelo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recuerda que todas las clases que crees en tu proyecto heredan directamente de la clase **Object** por lo que al hacer una lista de **Object** te permite generalizar y por ende podrás hacer agregar casi cualquier clase a dicha **List**. Si otro programador ve dicha lista el podría pensar que almacenas objetos Cliente, Animal, Instrumento, etc...... como dije, se puede generalizar.

Cuando haces una lista:

```
List<Cliente> miLista = ArrayList<>();
```

Estás indicando **explicitamente** que la lista solo permitirá agregar objetos **Cliente**, esto le ayudará a otro programador identificar claramente el tipo de objeto (Clase) que está usando la lista.

**En resumen** se usa el nombre de la clase en la lista para ser claros en el código.

> ¿Que implicaciones tiene, crear un ArrayList de una clase dentro de la
>   propia clase?
>
> ```
> public class Cliente(){
> private ArrayList<Cliente> queryResults = null;
>
> public Cliente(){
>
> }
>
> private String nombre = null;
> private String apellidos = null;
>
> //getters setters }
> ```

Cada vez que crees una **instancia** del objeto **Cliente** estarás creando junto con esa instancia una Lista nula que se llenará con datos hasta que hagas la consulta a la base de datos para obtener ciertos registros y guardarlos en la lista, luego podrás hacer tu filtro.

Si lo que quieres es mapear los registros de la base de datos a Clases en tu proyecto puedes usar cualquiera de estos patrones de diseño: https://www.ecodeup.com/patrones-de-diseno-en-java-mvc-dao-y-dto/

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, le echaré un vistazo al link que has pasado!